# How to get struct address inside array of structs?

Tags: c

I'm trying to get struct's address.

I want to  get address in an `int *`, and I want to change address by adding numbers to the `int *`. I tried several ways, but I can't solve it.

```
struct num_d {
    unsigned char data;    
    unsigned char pad1;
    unsigned char pad2;
    unsigned char pad3;
};
```

```
struct num_d **m = malloc(sizeof(struct num_d *) * row);   

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)                       
{                                                   
    m[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct num_d) * col);    
}
```

How can I get `m[0][0]`'s address in an `int *`?

Comment: SImply `(int *)&m[0][0]`?

Comment: Where is the `int` that you want to address? You have `char`s in the struct.

Comment: Perhaps you want a `union` instead of a `struct`... but I can only guess at what you are really trying to do because you haven't told us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first things first lets `typedef` your struct, so we can type less and be more clear:

```
typedef struct num_d num_d;
```

**void pointer**

A pointer to void is a **"generic"** pointer type. A `void *` can be converted to any other pointer type **without an explicit cast**. we cannot de-reference a `void *` or do pointer arithmetic with it; you must convert it to a complete data type pointer first (like `int*` e.g.) then do the de-refrence or the pointer arithmetic.

Now, `malloc()` return a `void*` which points to the allocated heap buffer (if malloc successed in allocation other wise null is the return value).

you code become:

```
num_d** m = malloc(sizeof(num_d*) * row);  /*m is an array of void* pointers (not initialized)*/ 

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)                       
{                                                   
    m[i] = malloc(sizeof(num_d) * col); /*in each element in m you have a void* that points to struct num_d on the heap*/    
}
```

the `sizeof(void*)` is the same as sizeof any pointer (except function pointers in some machines/os).

**putting it all together**

> How can I get m[0][0]'s address in an int *?

This is a wrong question! because m is an array of `void*` to "num_d structs" (holding the num_d heap address).

if you want the start address of the `i-th num_d` struct in the array `m`, then, just return the `void*` in the index `i` in this array `m[i]`. and if you want to cast it just cast it (no  need actually) just assign it:

```
int* ptr = m[i];
```

Take in mind that compilers will warn you, regarding the assignment above (but this assignment is supported and legal) :

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

or (no need again):

```
int* ptr = (int*)m[i];
```

I don't know why you need such behavior, it makes more sense to cast to `num_d*`

if you want the address of the first data member in the struct `num_d`, then you must cast to the appropriate data type to get the expected data:

```
unsigned char data = ((num_d*)m[i])->data;

unsigned char* p_data = &((num_d*)m[i])->data;
```

Comment: @Park - glad to help you. I hope that my answer helpped you and make things more clear. if you find it useful and clear please accept and vote it (pushing the V nearby). thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have the address in an `int*` in order to be adding to it. The way that `[]` works, is that it adds to the pointer and dereferences.

You can just add to `*(m[0] + 1)` to get the second element.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

int *ptr = (int *) m[0];